# GMSGroundOverlay animating - should I be using a CATiledLayer?

Tags: ios, crash, overlay, google-maps-sdk-ios, catiledlayer

I am experimenting with the Google Maps for iOS SDK latest version 1.2.1.2944 to animate a `GMSGroundOverlay`. The user has control over the image sequence, so using an animated `UIImage` isn't a possibility sadly, so i'm loading in the `UIImage` on the fly. The `GMSGroundOverlay.icon` is set to the `UIImage` that is being updated.

Aside from high memory usage, I seem to have struck a limitation in that whenever I try to overlay a `UIImage` using `GMSGroundOverlay.icon` that is more than 1000px x 1000px, it crashes. Referencing a `UIImage` of 1000px x 1000px gets around the crash.

It strikes me though that maybe I should utilise `CATiledLayer` for handling the image to only load into memory and subsequently into the icon property of `GMSGroundOverlay`, but has anyone had any experience of using `CATiledLayer` with Google Maps for iOS SDK and sequencing images as an animated `GMSGroundOverlay`?

Comment: I'm having just the same problem, though the threshold I'm seeing for crashes is even lower. I'd love to see a solution for this.

Comment: I would like a solution for all kinds of GMSOverlays

Comment: I dont see how you want to use TiledLayer..the overlay uses a UIImage ...

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from pressinganswer.com, i think it may helps you.

As currently I cannot use the "position" keypath for animating, I ended up animating it using the "latitude" and "longitude" keypaths separately.

First calculate the points and add them to 2 separate arrays, one for latitude value (y) and one for longitude (x) and then use the values property in CAKeyFrameAnimation to animate. Create 2 CAKeyFrameAnimation objects (1 for each axis) and group them together using CAAnimationGroup and animate them together to form a circle.

In my equation I vary the length of the radius on each axis so that I can also generate an oval path.

```
NSMutableArray *latitudes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:21];
    NSMutableArray *longitudes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:21];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        CGFloat radians = (float)i * ((2.0f * M_PI) / 20.0f);

        // Calculate the x,y coordinate using the angle
        CGFloat x = hDist * cosf(radians);
        CGFloat y = vDist * sinf(radians);

        // Calculate the real lat and lon using the
        // current lat and lon as center points.
        y = marker.position.latitude + y;
        x = marker.position.longitude + x;


        [longitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x]];
        [latitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y]];
    }

    CAKeyframeAnimation *horizontalAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"longitude"];
    horizontalAnimation.values = longitudes;
    horizontalAnimation.duration = duration;

    CAKeyframeAnimation *verticleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"latitude"];
    verticleAnimation.values = latitudes;
    verticleAnimation.duration = duration;

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [[CAAnimationGroup alloc] init];
    group.animations = @[horizontalAnimation, verticleAnimation];
    group.duration = duration;
    group.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [marker.layer addAnimation:group forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"circular-%@",marker.description]];
```

Comment: This is not the GMSGroundOverlay. You are showing a GMSMarker. The overlay does not provide the same access to the 'layer'